# Lazy Approval In SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, approval, ms-flow

I want to create a Lazy approval for SharePoint Online Using MS Flow.

I want to create a same flow as a below link using MS flow:
[WORKFLOW LAZY APPROVAL](https://wonderlaura.com/2015/09/15/workflow-lazy-approval/).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **Approvals** in Microsoft Flow and you can respond to your approvals (Approve or Reject) and provide an optional message directly from your **outlook inbox**.

**Microsoft Learn - Official documentation**: [Build an approval request](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/build-more-flows/2-flow-create-approval-request).

[image]

**Reference**: [Respond to your approvals from your inbox and Set an Approval Expiry](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/actionable-messages-approvals/).